# Python Image Library Error - Caught IOError while rendering: not enough data

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, sorl-thumbnail

I have created a website which is using the sorl-thumbnail to resize the images thats uploaded. Most of the images are getting resized without any issues but for few am getting the following error :

```
Caught IOError while rendering: not enough data
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/user/nash22/photographs/
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Caught IOError while rendering: not enough data
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py in load, line 382
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.1
```

I searched on google but could not find any relevant answers. Could someone please help me what happened and how i can fix it? Thank You.

### EDIT

Complete Traceback

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 111, in get_response    response = callback(request,
>   *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/swaroop/project/apps/photography/views.py",
>   line 702, in showPhoto    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
>
> File
>   "/lib/python2.7/django/shortcuts/**init**.py",
>   line 20, in render_to_response    return
>   HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
>   **httpresponse_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/lib/python2.7/django/template/loader.py",
>   line 188, in render_to_string    return t.render(context_instance)
>
> File
>   "/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py",
>   line 123, in render    return self._render(context)
>
> File
>   "/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py",
>   line 117, in _render    return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File
>   "/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py",
>   line 744, in render    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
>
> File
>   "/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py",
>   line 757, in render_node    return node.render(context)
>
> File
>   "/lib/python2.7/django/template/loader_tags.py",
>   line 127, in render    return compiled_parent._render(context)
>
> File
>   "/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py",
>   line 117, in _render    return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File
>   "/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py",
>   line 744, in render    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
>
> File
>   "/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py",
>   line 757, in render_node    return node.render(context)
>
> File
>   "/lib/python2.7/django/template/loader_tags.py",
>   line 64, in render    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File
>   "/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py",
>   line 744, in render    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
>
> File
>   "/lib/python2.7/django/template/base.py",
>   line 757, in render_node    return node.render(context)
>
> File
>   "/lib/python2.7/sorl/thumbnail/templatetags/thumbnail.py",
>   line 45, in render    return self._render(context)
>
> File
>   "/lib/python2.7/sorl/thumbnail/templatetags/thumbnail.py",
>   line 97, in *render    file*, geometry, **options
>
> File "/lib/python2.7/sorl/thumbnail/base.py", line 61,
>   in get_thumbnail    thumbnail)
>
> File "/lib/python2.7/sorl/thumbnail/base.py", line 86,
>   in _create_thumbnail    image = default.engine.create(source_image,
>   geometry, options)
>
> File "/lib/python2.7/sorl/thumbnail/engines/base.py",
>   line 15, in create    image = self.orientation(image, geometry,
>   options)
>
> File "/lib/python2.7/sorl/thumbnail/engines/base.py",
>   line 26, in orientation    return self._orientation(image)
>
> File
>   "/lib/python2.7/sorl/thumbnail/engines/pil_engine.py",
>   line 29, in _orientation    exif = image._getexif()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py",
>   line 381, in _getexif    info.load(file)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py",
>   line 382, in load    raise IOError, "not enough data"
>
> IOError: not enough data

Answer (score 7):

*update*

`image._getexif` is claimed to be highly experimental. Refs [sorl-thumbnail](https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail/blob/master/sorl/thumbnail/engines/pil_engine.py#L27) and [issue #98](https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail/issues/98), you could update the code to be

```
def _orientation(self, image):
    try:
        exif = image._getexif()
    except (AttributeError, IOError):
        exif = None
```

---

It's caused by PIL's attempt to load a corrupted or possibly unsupported TIFF file.
Normally when you use `forms.ImageField`, Django would check the correctness of uploaded images.
Thus you need to:

- ensure that you're using `forms.ImageField`, which is default for `models.ImageField`, to deal w/ uploading in your view
- check the uploaded image by

  ```
  from PIL import Image
  Image.open(path).load()
  ```
- use toolkit that processing TIFF to open the image and, if you can open it , save it to Jpeg or Png and update the field of the model instance to point to the new file.

Also you could limit user to upload normal formats such as jpeg/png/gif instead of TIFF

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I checked and following are my observation:
1) I am using forms.ImageField
2) I tried to load the image that is creating the issue using load and am getting following result:
<PixelAccess object at 0x7f811a22dd30>
So i guess the image is not corrupted.
3) The image is a jpeg image and not a TIFF image
So everything looks valid and now we are back to the original question. Any other possible reasons for the error I got?

Comment: @swaroop hmm, could you post the sorl-thumbnail traceback then?

Comment: I have appended traceback in my original post. I could notice in the traceback that the sorl-thumbnail is loading TiffImagePlugin.py which means its detecting image as a tiff. But the image passed to the sorl-thumbnail is a jpeg rather than a TIFF image. So am confused now

Comment: @swaroop the code `_getexif` in `PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py` relies on `TiffImagePlugIn` to deal w/ embedded tiff which contains exif info, you could see comments inside the function. Its also claims to be *highly experimental*...

Comment: @swaroop if the embedded tiff is OK, then its probably a bug and you could submit it like [this issue](https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail/issues/98). You could also catch the IOError as the issue's solution.

Comment: It seems that the issue was a bug in TiffImagePlugIn. So I switched to GD Library and now everything is working fine now.

Comment: FYI the issue #98 has a Pull request and had been merged in the development branch and it's available in http://github.com/mariocesar/sorl-thumbnail